# MyBatis occasionally can't find records in the database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, mybatis

I am using Spring Boot(2.3.10.RELEASE) + MyBatis + HikariCP(3.4.5) to connect to PostgreSQL 13, today I found a query could not fetch data from database. I am absolutely sure the query want to find data exists in database. When I trace the log, it shows like this:

```
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5f3949a1]
2021-05-16 11:35:12.806 ERROR 12273 --- [-post-service-1] c.d.s.p.s.impl.article.ArticleService    : query failed:cruise:article:detail:2416846
2021-05-16 11:35:13.070  INFO 12273 --- [-post-service-1] c.d.s.p.common.mq.StreamMessageListener  : stream message。messageId=1621136113069-0, stream=pydolphin:stream:article, body={id=2416847, sub_source_id=1168}
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7f8a0ee1] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@803742617 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@35a5c30d] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT 'true' AS QUERYID, id, user_id, sub_source_id, created_time, updated_time, sub_status FROM sub_relation WHERE (sub_status = ? AND sub_source_id = ?)
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - ==> Parameters: 1(Integer), 1168(Long)
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7f8a0ee1]
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@94502f9] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@858597637 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@35a5c30d] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT id, user_id, title, author, guid, created_time, updated_time, link, pub_time, sub_source_id, cover_image, channel_reputation, editor_pick FROM article WHERE id = ?
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - ==> Parameters: 2416847(Long)
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - <==      Total: 0
DEBUG [dolphin-post-service-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@94502f9]
2021-05-16 11:35:13.074 ERROR 12273 --- [-post-service-1] c.d.s.p.s.impl.article.ArticleService    : query failed:cruise:article:detail:2416847
```

and this is my Java code:

```
private void loadArticleFromDatabase(List<ArticleDTO> articles, Long articleId, String cachedKey) {
    Article dbArticle = articleMapper.selectByPrimaryKey(articleId);
    if (dbArticle == null) {
        log.error("query failed:" + cachedKey);
        return;
    }
    ArticleDTO articleDTO = appendArticleAttachInfo(dbArticle);
    articles.add(articleDTO);
}
```

and this is my MyBatis.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "./mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false"/>
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false"/>
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
        <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true"/>
        <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true"/>
        <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="5"/>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
        <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true"/>
        <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="Integer" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <typeAlias alias="Long" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <typeAlias alias="HashMap" type="java.util.HashMap" />
        <typeAlias alias="LinkedHashMap" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap" />
        <typeAlias alias="ArrayList" type="java.util.ArrayList" />
        <typeAlias alias="LinkedList" type="java.util.LinkedList" />
    </typeAliases>
    <plugins>
        <plugin interceptor="misc.interceptor.db.DefaultTimeInterceptor"/>
        <plugin interceptor="misc.interceptor.db.DynamicDataSourceInterceptor"/>
        <plugin interceptor="com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor">
            <property name="param1" value="value1"/>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

The weird thing is, the app runs fine for a period of time, and suddenly can not query data from the database. Where is the problem and what should I do to fix it? This is my `DataSource.config` about transactionManager:

```
@Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactory")
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    bean.setConfigLocation(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"));
    bean.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:mybatis/mapper/*/*.xml"));
    Interceptor[] plugins = {paginationInterceptor,defaultTimeInterceptor};
    bean.setPlugins(plugins);
    return bean.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

As I said am sure the article id exists in database:

[image]

by the way this is my `DynamicDataSourceInterceptor` class, this class tried to determin the database should using master node or slave node:

```
package misc.interceptor.db;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import misc.config.db.DataSourceContextHolder;
import misc.constant.db.ConstantPool;
import org.apache.ibatis.executor.Executor;
import org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.BoundSql;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlCommandType;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.*;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * @date: 2019-09-17 20:28
 */
@Slf4j
@Intercepts({
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class}),
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "query", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class, RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class}),
})
public class DynamicDataSourceInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final String regex = ".*insert\\u0020.*|.*delete\\u0020.*|.update\\u0020.*";

    /**
     * 
     * @param invocation
     * @return
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        boolean synchronizationActive = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
        Object[] objects = invocation.getArgs();
        MappedStatement mappedStatement = (MappedStatement) objects[0];
        String lookupKey = ConstantPool.MASTER_KEY;
        if (synchronizationActive != true){
            if (mappedStatement.getSqlCommandType().equals(SqlCommandType.SELECT)){
                if (mappedStatement.getId().contains(SelectKeyGenerator.SELECT_KEY_SUFFIX)){
                    lookupKey = ConstantPool.MASTER_KEY;
                } else {
                    BoundSql boundSql = mappedStatement.getSqlSource().getBoundSql(objects[1]);
                    String sqlstr = boundSql.getSql();
                    String sql = sqlstr.toLowerCase(Locale.CHINA).replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]", " ");
                    if (sql.matches(regex)){
                        lookupKey = ConstantPool.MASTER_KEY;
                    } else {
                        lookupKey = ConstantPool.SLAVE_KEY;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            lookupKey = ConstantPool.MASTER_KEY;
        }
        DataSourceContextHolder.setDataSourceKey(lookupKey);
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param target
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        if (target instanceof Executor){
            return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
        } else {
            return target;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param properties
     */
    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {

    }
}
```

because now the master node and slave node has the same database configuration(My database only hava one node now). so it seems not the `DynamicDataSourceInterceptor` problem I think. This is the breakpoiont captured:

[image]

Comment: I think your focus is on the wrong thing here. As far as I can tell from those logs, the article with id 2416847 does not exist. Please edit your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: I am sure the article with id 2416847 in database exists.@MarkRotteveel

Comment: That may be, but I don't understand why your focus is on the debug message _"SqlSession was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active"_, as far as I can tell from a quick Google, that just means that you're not in a Spring-managed transaction, which means it's unlikely to be related to your problem.

Comment: I also think the debug message is not relate to the real question, but that's all message I could get to find where is the problem. After hourly searching, I could not found an answser. After I restart the application, the problem disappeared, but I know it will come back again because it is not the first time   i face the problem. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @Dolphin Try removing those interceptors. `DynamicDataSourceInterceptor` looks suspicious, especially.

Comment: I read the DynamicDataSourceInterceptor class, could not find any evidence to prove the DynamicDataSourceInterceptor cause the problem I think. @ave

Comment: @Dolphin Well, I'll take your word for it. From MyBatis point of view, the query returns no rows and that is all that matters, nothing complicated. If the row is not created in the same session, the query may be executed against a different host, database or schema. Checking the server's query log might give you more clues.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found that the article write client did not commit transaction immediate. The transaction commit was behand the Mybatis search, tweak the write Python client code like this:

```
article_count = count(guid, title, source.id)
        if article_count == 0:
            with session_scope() as local_count_session:
                local_count_session.add(article)
                local_count_session.flush()
                # add this line to commit transaction
                local_count_session.commit() 
                push_message_to_stream(article)
        else:
            logger.warn("this article already exists in database,title:" + title + ",link:" + link)
        return article
```